# Implicit Model to View-Model conversion in DataContext (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a very general question and I'm not quite sure if this one has asked/answered before.

I have a Model (Workflow) in my application. Currently I'm assigning the Model to the DataContext of my window / view, but actually I want to create a ViewModel around the Workflow and assign this ViewModel to the DataContext.

The problem is, that the window and views are created using DataTemplates and lists where only the model is assigned, since everything is created in the remote backend. The front-end gets the information about the model which is associated automatically in the DataContext when view is created.

Of course I can create the ViewModel manually when the DataContext is set. But then I need to change the DataContext and set it to the ViewModel and the old DataContext is gone. Besides I have to do it manually although it could be easily done in XAML using a resource.

Is there a pattern that copes with this requirement? I haven't found anything.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: *The problem is, that the window and views are created using DataTemplates and lists where only the model is assigned*... why can't you just assign the view model as the `DataTemplate.DataType` property? You could even do that in local `Resources`.

Comment: I haven't tried the DataType so far - I will try. The question nevertheless is, how do I make the DataContext of the DataTemplate to the newly created ViewModel? Maybe the answer is in your statement but I need to try. Do you have a small example of how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `DataTemplate` into a particular view's `Resources` section:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:YourViewModel}">
    <Views:YourView />
</DataTemplate>
```

In this particular case, the `YourView` view will be rendered whenever an object of type `YourViewModel` is found in the UI and the view model will implicitly be set as the `YourView.DataContext` property value. Using this `DataTemplate`, you can display the `YourView` view like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PropertyOfTypeOfYourViewModel}" />
```

Note that this `DataTemplate` should be declared in a `Resources` section *outside of the `YourView` view* and *in scope of the `ContentControl`*.

Comment: Thank you. I was more hoping of a solution where I can changed the data context of the DataTemplate, but I guess this is not possible. I also don't have a way where I can assign the model either by giving it as an argument or as a property. I'll have to dig a littler deeper.